# ThreadPool getActiveCount() vs getPoolSize()

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Although this topic has been discussed broadly in other posts I want to present my use case and clarify .So apologies if I am wasting anyone's time. I have the following runnable implementation. Basically infinitely running thread unless `java.lang.Error` gets thrown by the business logic.

```java
public void run (){
    while(true){
        try{
            //business logic
        }catch(Exception ex){
             
        }
    }
}
```

I have about 30 of the above threads started from ExecutorService.

```java
private final ExecutorService normalPriorityExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        normalPriorityExecutorService.submit(//Above Runnable);
}
```

I want to check and kill the JVM process if the thread count becomes zero on this Executor Service.

```java
if (normalPriorityExecutorService instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor && ((ThreadPoolExecutor) normalPriorityExecutorService).getActiveCount() ==0) {
    log.error("No Normal Priority response listeners available. Shutting down App!");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

From my reading since these runnable threads are infinitely running  under normal circumstances I will have 30 of them active unless they get killed by runtime Errors.

Question is using `getActiveCount()` the right approach for my use case ? By the way, when I tried using `getPoolSize()` instead of `getActiveCount()`, I did not get the right behavior while testing (I forcefully threw an error to kill a specific thread) and the `poolSize` still remained thirty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you never use the thread pool as a pool, using a thread pool is overkill. Just create a thread group and start your threads.

```java
private final ThreadGroup normalPriorityThreadGroup = new ThreadGroup("NormalPriority");
```

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    new Thread(this.normalPriorityThreadGroup, runnable, "NormalPriority-" + 1).start();
}
```

```java
if (this.normalPriorityThreadGroup.activeCount() == 0) {
    log.error("No Normal Priority response listeners available. Shutting down App!");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Hello Andreas - Thank you . Just curious as why you say 'you never use the thread pool as a pool' . My understanding it is the job of executor service to manage the thread pool after we decide what kind of thread pool we want with the count of listeners . What am i missing ? BTW i got the idea of active count and so far it seems to work well in lower environments .

Comment: @user7246161 A pool is something that stores objects for re-use, so that fewer objects can help/service more uses. Useful when objects are "expensive", e.g. monetarily (vehicles in a motor pool), performance (connection pool, thread pool, because database connections and threads are both slow to start up), and for resource management (limit number of thread). Your code establishes 30 threads up front, then never re-uses a thread, hence the code is not *using* the pool aspect of the thread pool.